# New siphon advice

Tags: bottling, siphon

I've been using buckets, taps and hoses so far but want to start using carboys so I need a siphon.
Since there are several types around, what do you suggest?
I've heard that automatic ones are a bit tougher to clean, what's your experience with them?

I'd buy it here (posting the link so you can see what I can choose from): https://www.brouwland.com/en/our-products/bottling/siphons-and-accessories/complete-siphons

Answer (score 2):

I like this one.
https://www.morebeer.com/products/sterile-siphon-starter-3-5-6-65-gallon-carboy-smooth-necks.html

Because of the design simular to the one you linked, you can use very low co2 pressure to push the beer. This gives the added ability over pump type siphons to completely eliminate oxygen contact with your beer.

This is very useful for purging a secondary of oxygen. Fill with sanitizer and siphon using co2 results in a secondary filled with co2 and not air.

Comment: Nice, I'd like to buy it. Anyone knows where to find it in the EU?